# Select2 - Can't select a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

Release version (Select 4.0.1)

HTML

```
<select id="search_customers" style="width: 300px;"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#search_customers").select2({
  multiple: false,
  allowClear: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "@Url.Action("
    SearchCustomers ", "
    Home ")",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        id: params.term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      return {
        results: data
      } // Data is a List<T> of id an text
    },
  }
});
```

The dropdown works, and I can see my records, however, when I click on one of the options the box closes, and the selected record isn't shown. My box looks like this

[image: capture]

I've tried everything I can think of. The issue appears in all browsers. The data being return is a list of id/text pairs.

Controller code

```
var customers = this.service.SearchCustomers(id).Select(x => new { id = x.CustomerID, text = x.CustomerName }).ToList();

return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: I could, but I wouldn't know how to fake the ajax request....

Comment: Echoing: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: This should work but it's not..... https://jsfiddle.net/sjaggggr/1/

Answer (score 0):

My customer ID's had leading spaces for some reason. (Old ERP system), so adding a .Trim() call to the select statement on the customer ID fixed it. Apparently select2 doesn't like "    56", but "56" is fine!